# NSStreamStatus changing manually

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstream

is there any way to change the streamStatus manually

```
   NSStreamStatusNotOpen = 0,
   NSStreamStatusOpening = 1,
   NSStreamStatusOpen = 2,
   NSStreamStatusReading = 3,
   NSStreamStatusWriting = 4,
   NSStreamStatusAtEnd = 5,
   NSStreamStatusClosed = 6,
   NSStreamStatusError = 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSStreamStatus](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is for Getting Stream Information. So, it cannot be changed manually as it provides receiver’s status.